# Only the half of my form is printed when I run my jsp page

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

when I run my editController.jsp page, in which there is a form with three selects and a button, only the three selects (that are in a table) are printed and not the button. My code is the following:

```
    <h2 class="error">Date</h2>
    <div id="edit">
        <form action="editController.jsp" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">    
        <table border="0">
            <caption><b> Birth Date </b></caption>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="day">
                    <option value="day">Day</option>
<%
                    for(int i=1; i<=31; i++){
%>              
                        <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %></option>
<%      
                    }
%>              
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="month">
                    <option value="month">Month</option>
<%
                    for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
%>              
                        <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %></option>
<%      
                    }
%>                      
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="year">
                    <option value="year">Year</option>
<%
                    for(int i=1900; i<=2014; i++){
%>              
                        <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %></option>
<%      
                    }
%>                  
                    </select>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css code is:

```
.error{
    color:#FF0000;
}
#edit{
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
    border: 3px solid #566D7E;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#4C787E;  
}
```

I also use Bootstrap.
I guess I have make a mistake but I can't find it!! Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a [jsfid](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this. Will it help if I send the whole code of my jsp page?

Comment: it's not a good idea to post *all* the code, if you can make a link to the all code it would be better but if you don't know how to do that you can still post the related code like CSS links and JS scripts.

Comment: I posted my CSS code and I don't have JS scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses `"form-group"`, `"form-control"` classes for the elements of the form. The code without scriptlets that you use to fill the options of select tags

```
<div id="edit"> 
<h2 class="error">Date</h2>
        <form action="editController.jsp" method="post" role="form">  
    <div class="form-group">
      <caption><b> Birth Date </b></caption>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="day">
                    <option value="day">Day</option>

                        <option value=" i "> i </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <select class="form-control" name="month">
                    <option value="month">Month</option>
                        <option value="i "> i </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control" name="year">
                    <option value="year">Year</option>
                        <option value=" i"> i </option>
                    </select>   
                </td>
            </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-default ">Save</button>

        </form>
</div>
```

You can use JSTL `forEach` tag to do the same instead of scriptlets.

[JSFiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/yjqah2zL/5/)

Comment: So the problem in my code is that I don't use JS? Is it necessary? Did you find any mistake in my code?

Comment: The bootstrap has js and it's needed to function correctly. You forgot to use "form-control" class. This is your mistake.

Comment: You have other mistakes when using scriptlets in the code. Do you want to know how scriptles are discouraged on SO?